# Filling the values of an array with values of other table

Tags: arrays, postgresql, error-handling

I have a table (my_table2) in postgresql which contains a column with array type. I want values of column val1 of my_table1 to be first elements of my array (array_col) and val2 to be second elements of array_col. I came up with this query:

```
update my_table2
set array_col=array[
    (
    select val1 from my_table1)
    , (select val2 from my_table1)
    ]
```

but I got an error when I run it: 
*ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression*
Is there a method to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your subqueries, `select val1 from my_table1` or `select val2 from my_table1`, are returning more than one row.  If you're going to specific a subquery for each element, then it can only return one element.

Depending on what you have...you might be looking at something more like :

Concat the two together?

`update my_table2 set array_col=array(select val1 from my_table1)||array(select val2 from my_table1)`

Just get one from each?

`update my_table2 set array_col=array[(select val1 from my_table1 limit 1),(select val2 from my_table1 limit 1)]`